# Purpose of .local file

Tags: macos

I am preparing to migrate to a new MBP and I am cleaning up files. I have a directory ~/Documents/Garys-MacBook-2.local which contains a lot of files (34K for 115 GB) many of which seem to recursively nested.  What is the purpose of this and is there any way to clean it up? Currently on 12.0.1.